# when i save to my database i don't receive my data

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

when i input data in the form to get Smtp, according to my code am to get the data and save it to my database but its not working, i don't receive any data info in my mongodb, i only get the Date

[this is what my database looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlSja.png)

my view(ejs)

```
    <h1 class="mt-4">Dashboard</h1>



    <div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
          <div class="card card-body">
            <h1 class="text-center mb-3">
              <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Add Smtp
            </h1>
            <% include ./partials/messages %>
            <form action="/users/mail" method="POST">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="smtpUsername">smtpUsername</label>
                <input
                  type="name"
                  id="smtpUsername"
                  name="smtpUsername"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Enter smtpUsername"
                  value="<%= typeof smtpUsername != 'undefined' ? smtpUsername : '' %>"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="smtpPassword">smtpPassword</label>
                <input
                  type="name"
                  id="smtpPassword"
                  name="smtpPassword"  
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Enter smtpPassword"
                  value="<%= typeof smtpPassword != 'undefined' ? smtpPassword : '' %>"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="smtpUrl">smtpUrl</label>
                <input
                  type="name"
                  id="smtpUrl"
                  name="smtpUrl"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Enter smtpUrl"
                  value="<%= typeof smtpUrl != 'undefined' ? smtpUrl : '' %>"
                />
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                Add Smtp
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



    <div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
          <div class="card card-body">
            <h1 class="text-center mb-3">
              <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> send mail
            </h1>
            <% include ./partials/messages %>
            <form action="/users/mail" method="POST">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="to">to</label>
                <input
                  type="name"
                  id="to"
                  name="to"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Enter to"
                  value="<%= typeof to != 'undefined' ? to : '' %>"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="bcc">bcc</label>
                <input
                  type="name"
                  id="bcc"
                  name="bcc"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Enter bcc"
                  value="<%= typeof bcc != 'undefined' ? bcc : '' %>"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cc">cc</label>
                <input
                  type="name"
                  id="cc"
                  name="name"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Enter cc"
                  value="<%= typeof cc != 'undefined' ? cc : '' %>"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subject">subject</label>
                <input
                  type="name"
                  id="subject"
                  name="subject"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Enter subject"
                  value="<%= typeof subject != 'undefined' ? subject : '' %>"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message">message</label>
                <input
                  type="name"
                  id="message"
                  name="message"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Enter message"
                  value="<%= typeof message != 'undefined' ? message : '' %>"
                />
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                Register
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



    <a href="/users/logout" class="btn btn-secondary">Logout</a>
```

when i input data in the form to get Smtp, according to my code am to get the data and save it to my database but its not working, i don't receive any data info in my mongodb, i only get the Date

my schema

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    const MailSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        to: {
            type: String,

        },
        cc: {
            type: String,

        },
        bcc: {
            type: String,
        },
        subject: {
            type: String,

        },
        message: {  
            type: String,

        },
        attachment: {
            type: String,
        },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },

    });

    const SmtpSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        smtpUrl: {
            type: String,
            required: true

        },
        smtpUsername: {
            type: String,
            required: true

        },
        smtpPassword: {
            type: String,
            required: true

        },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },

    });





    const Mail = mongoose.model('Mail', MailSchema);
    const Smtp = mongoose.model('Smtp', SmtpSchema);


    module.exports = Mail;
```

when i input data in the form to get Smtp, according to my code am to get the data and save it to my database but its not working, i don't receive any data info in my mongodb, i only get the Date

my Route

```
    router.get('/mail', forwardAuthenticated, (req, res) =>
        res.render('mail', {
            user: req.user,
            mail: req.mail

        })
    );
    router.post('/mail', (req, res) => {
        const { to, cc, bcc, subject, message, attachment } = req.body;
        const { smtpUrl, smtpUsername, smtpPassword } = req.body;

        console.log(smtpUrl)
        console.log(smtpPassword)
        console.log(smtpUsername)



        let errors = [];

        if (!smtpUrl || !smtpUsername || !smtpPassword) {
            errors.push({ msg: 'Add an account' });
            res.render('mail', {
            smtpUrl,
            smtpPassword,
            smtpUsername
            });

        }else{
          console.log(smtpUrl)
          console.log(smtpPassword)
          console.log(smtpUsername)
          const newSmtp = new Smtp({
            smtpUrl,
            smtpPassword,
            smtpUsername
        });

        newSmtp
        .save()
        .then(mail => {
            req.flash(
                'success_msg',
                'Account Added'
            );

        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
        if (!to || !subject || !message) {
            errors.push({ msg: 'Please enter all fields' });
        }


        if (errors.length > 0) {
            res.render('mail', {
                errors,
                to,
                cc,
                bcc,
                subject,
                message,
                attachment,
            });
        } else {
            const newMail = new Mail({
                to,
                cc,
                bcc,
                subject,
                message,
                attachment,
            });


            let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: smtpUrl,
                auth: {
                    user: smtpUsername,
                    pass: smtpPassword
                }
            });

            let mailOptions = {
                from: smtpUsername,
                to: to,
                subject: subject,
                text: `${message}`
            };

            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {

                    newMail
                        .save()
                        .then(mail => {
                            req.flash(
                                'success_msg',
                                'mail sent'
                            );

                        })
                        .catch(err => console.log(err));
                    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
                }
            });





        }


    })
```

Comment: I did not go into much detail, however I can see you are not exporting Smtp, just as you did with Mail, else your instantiation won't work; so module.exports = Smtp

Comment: `const { to, cc, bcc, subject, message, attachment } = req.body; const { smtpUrl, smtpUsername, smtpPassword } = req.body; ` what are you doing here? I prefer to put them separately like `x = req.body. x` or put them in one line according to their order `{x, y} =req.body ` if your code is rewriting the first line

Comment: `const { to, cc, bcc, subject, message, attachment, smtpUrl, smtpUsername, smtpPassword } = req.body;
` try this and put them according to their order.

Comment: @codabae any update?